# Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ForEach method

Tags: c#

I wanna declare new extension method which similar to [List.ForEach Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx).

What I wanna archive:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
   { "K1", "V1" },
   { "K2", "V2" },
   { "K3", "V3" },
};


dict.ForEach((x, y) => 
{
   Console.WriteLine($"(Key: {x}, value: {y})");
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an extension method easily:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Action<TKey, TValue> invoke)
    {
        foreach(var kvp in dictionary)
            invoke(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Using like this:

```
dict.ForEach((x, y) => 
{
   Console.WriteLine($"(Key: {x}, value: {y})");
});
```

Produces

```
Key: K1, value: V1
Key: K2, value: V2
Key: K3, value: V3
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
   { "K1", "V1" },
   { "K2", "V2" },
   { "K3", "V3" },
};

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> myData in dict )
{
    // Do something with myData.Value or myData.Key
}
```

This is the extension method:

```
public static void ForEach<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Action<TKey, TValue> invokeMe)
{
    foreach(var keyValue in dictionary)
    {
        invokeMe(keyValue.Key, keyValue.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to use lambda expression inside the loop?

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve here? i mean any add\delete things @HappyCoding?

Comment: Your answer is not matched. I've shown pseudocode above

Comment: sorry i missed extension method part. updated now @HappyCoding

Answer (score 1):

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("hello", "bob");
dic.Foreach(x =>
{
   Console.WriteLine(x.Key + x.Value);
});


public static void Foreach<T, TY>(this Dictionary<T, TY> collection,   Action<T, TY> action)
{
    foreach (var kvp in collection)
    {
        action.Invoke(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: `action.Invoke(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);` can be shortened to `action(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);`

Answer (score 1):

1: Extension methods must be declared in a non-nested, non-generic, static class.
2: The 1st parameter must be annotated with the `this` keyword.

```
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<TKey, TValue>(
        this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
        Action<TKey, TValue> action) {

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair in dictionary) {
            action(pair.Key, pair.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

This method can then be called as if it were a regular instance method:

```
dict.ForEach((key, value) =>
    Console.WriteLine($"(Key: {key}, Value: {value})"));
```