# Is there a way to use .ForEach on Dictionary contents?

Tags: c#, .net

I changed a collection from `List` to `Dictionary` and it seems I need change from using `.ForEach()` to `foreach()` on it - regardless if I'm iterating the Dictionary itself, or `Dictionary.Values`.

It's no big deal but I've seen a few times slight discrepancies when you can and can't use LINQ, and I wondered if there *is* a way and I just missed it?

Comment: A dictionary is enumerable so all you have to do is do dict.Select() or dict.Where()

Comment: `.ForEach` is actually a [method on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=netcore-3.1) `List` not `IEnumerable` hence why its not working for `Dictionary` and not in Linq.

Comment: Also see question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101265/why-there-is-no-foreach-extension-method-on-ienumerable

Comment: Yeah I wondered what `Values` is... I thought that might ultimately be a `List` but apparently not. I wonder if there's a good technical reason or just 'because'?

Comment: Further reading [“foreach” vs “ForEach”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach)

Comment: That's interesting @PavelAnikhouski though one could surely make the same argument that `.ForEach` is fairly pointless for the same reasons. Anyway thanks for the link,

Comment: @Mr.Boy LINQ is declarative methods that don't modify source collection but rather filter/map in *a lazy way*. ForEach is is somewhat opposite of it... Indeed `Select(x => action(x)).All()` is rough equivalent of `.ForEach` but that's really confusing and regular `foreach` would be more self-documneting if you need non-lazy execution.

Comment: Is this asking about the `ForEach()` method specifically, or "`ForEach()` or similar/equivalent" (i.e. `foreach` and LINQ)? If the former, `List<>.ForEach()` can't be called on another class, of course. If the latter, I think that is a well-covered question already. See also: [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ForEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34416931/150605) method, [`Dictionary ForAll / ForEach method`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46229829/150605), [`Why does the generic Dictionary in .NET not provide a ForEach() method`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46229829/150605)?

Comment: Using a Select enumerates through the dictionary.  A dctionary is a List<KeyValuePair<key, object>>.  When using Select each object is KeyValuePair<key, object>.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov OK that clarifies a bit further. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `.ForEach()` is only defined on the `List<>` class.

You could either use `.ToList()` first to get access to `.ForEach` but that will, of course, lower the performance compared to just using `foreach` or you could create extension-methods for that:

```
public static void ForEach<T, U>(this Dictionary<T, U> d, Action<KeyValuePair<T, U>> a)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<T, U> p in d) { a(p); }
}

public static void ForEach<T, U>(this Dictionary<T, U>.KeyCollection k, Action<T> a)
{
    foreach (T t in k) { a(t); }
}

public static void ForEach<T, U>(this Dictionary<T, U>.ValueCollection v, Action<U> a)
{
    foreach (U u in v) { a(u); }
}
```

If you are interested in further information, there is already a similar [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141088/what-is-the-best-way-to-iterate-over-a-dictionary) on SO.

Comment: I mean in reality it seems not worth it. I can handle writing a loop, sometimes you just feel they're kind of dirty and old-fashioned ;)

Comment: I agree with what you said. :)